# Image File is not uploading to the IIS server

Tags: .net, iis, image-uploading

Image File is not uploading to the IIS server, the folder permission in the server is automatically set as read only. Can enbody give a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto to the folder that the file uploads to and set the security with write permission
if that does work add the everyone user to isolate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your Destination Folder --> Right Click the folder --> Properties --> Security Tab --> Edit Button--> Allow the Security. See the image below.

[image]

[image]